# jquery flot overlapping two labels

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

Hi all I'm working with a graphic of two labels, but the problem is that the labels overlap and what I want is a bar next to the other so that is visible on a comparison between the categories that I have is displayed. There is some property that allows me to separate them and they do not overlap?

```
var ms_data = [{
    "label": "Bar1",
    "data": [
        [0, 20],
        [1, 10],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 5],
        [4, 2]
    ]
}, {
    "label": "Bar2",
    "data": [
        [0, 15],
        [1, 8],
        [2, 9],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 7]
    ]
}, ];
var ms_ticks = [
    [0, "category1"],
    [1, "category2"],
    [2, "category3"],
    [3, "category4"],
    [4, "category5"]
];

function plotWithOptions() {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), ms_data, {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.6,
            series_spread: true,
            align: "center"
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: ms_ticks,
            autoscaleMargin: .10
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        }
    });
}
plotWithOptions();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem is either in dimensions of your plot or in the label font size.

If you're talking about bars, not labels, then to prevent overlapping you'll have to use the [flot-orderBars](https://github.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars) plugin (note the `bars { order: X }` object inside `ms_data` elements):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    var ms_data = [{
        "label": "Bar1",
        "data": [
            [0, 20],
            [1, 10],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 5],
            [4, 2]
        ],
        bars: {
           order: 0
        }
    }, {
        "label": "Bar2",
        "data": [
            [0, 15],
            [1, 8],
            [2, 9],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 7]
        ],
        bars: {
           order: 1
        }
    }, ];
                   var ms_ticks = [
                   [0, "category1"],
        [1, "category2"],
            [2, "category3"],
                [3, "category4"],
                    [4, "category5"]
                    ];
    
    function plotWithOptions() {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), ms_data, {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.3,
                /*series_spread: true,*/
                align: "center"
            },
            xaxis: {
                ticks: ms_ticks,
                autoscaleMargin: .10
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            }
        });
    }
    plotWithOptions();
    
});
```

```css
.demo-container {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 640px;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
 margin: 15px auto 30px auto;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background: #fff;
}

.demo-placeholder {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}

.legend table {
 border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery.flot -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<!-- Order Bars plugin -->
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars/master/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>


<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering really appreciate it, I tested your code and I did not work, the bars are overlapping, I have also tried other examples but still the same problem. Here a test code and the result:  http://jsfiddle.net/D3vilr3mix/L6cdr6cv/

Comment: thank you very much this if it worked perfect for me, and as for what Label and bars, was because I was trying all sorts of examples and none had worked for me. Thanks again